# Remove data in array based on its data value in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Database's Structure]

So I have array of maps that stored inside "categories". And I also have list of category IDs. I want to remove all the data inside of categories that doesn't contain the ID that I have. For the example, I have "a, f, z" (list of category IDs), then I want to remove all the data that doesn't have "a", "f", or "z" as its ID.

I'm really confused on how to achieve that, is that possible, if so, how can I do that? Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you can use List.forEach() to get each element of your array of maps then apply your logic.

Comment: Are you trying to access these in a known document or search for documents which contain the IDs?  Looking at your data model, I'd recommend, wherever possible, splitting complex arrays out into sub-collections.

Comment: I think I understand what you're after but something to keep in mind is the one thing Firestore is *not* good at is finding stuff that doesn't exist. In other words if there's a collection of recipes and you want to find all the one's that do not contain sugar, that's a challenge for Firestore; it's strength is finding existing stuff. If may help if you can clarify the question; there are a couple `id` fields so which one are you referring to. Also, when you say 'remove all the data', what does that mean? Remove the `items` data or the entire element of the array or something else?

Comment: @Jay I want to remove the entire element of the array. I have solved this question actually, by using forEach as Diwyansh suggested. I don't know if that's best practice or not but I think I should've splitted my complex array to subCollections like Jason Berryman said.

Comment: So you're solution is to load the entire collection in and filter in code. While that's an option it doesn't scale well - if you have 10,000 documents that could potentially load a LOT of data and overwhelm the device, causing a crash - it will also be slower. In general when working with potentially large datasets, let the server do the heavy lifting and let it present a smaller, manageable section of data to the device. But, glad you have a solution.